# Laggy UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableViewController` with 1000 row. Each cell contains label that fill with attributed string. Cell are self sizing cell and estimation is not correct in `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` so I did not use it (I don't no why my estimation cause to lag, I use `NSSting.boundingRectWithSize` for estimation). I have `UISlider` as SeekBar in bottom of my view, when I seek too middle of page main thread become busy with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and even I could not show waiting progress bar like HUD progress.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Aya Cell") as! AyaCell
    let detail = API.readingDetail[indexPath.row % API.readingDetail.count]


    cell.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

    switch detail {
    case .Persian:

        let text = translations.suras[self.sura.index-1].ayas[indexPath.row / API.readingDetail.count].text
        var textBackground = UIColor.clearColor()
        if translations.suras[self.sura.index-1].ayas[indexPath.row / API.readingDetail.count].shouldSelected == true {
            textBackground = UIColor.yellowColor()
        }

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: persianTextColor, NSFontAttributeName: AyaPersianFont!, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: backgroundColor])
        attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: " (\((indexPath.row / API.readingDetail.count+1).toArabicDigit()))", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: MojezeRedColor, NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "XNazanin", size: AyaFont!.pointSize*0.65)!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: AyaParagraphStyle]))
        cell.ayaTextLabel.attributedText = attributedText

    case .Arabic:
        let text = self.sura.ayas[indexPath.row / API.readingDetail.count].text

        var textBackground = UIColor.clearColor()
        if self.sura.ayas[indexPath.row / API.readingDetail.count].shouldSelected == true {
            textBackground = UIColor.yellowColor()
        }

        let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: arabicTextColor, NSFontAttributeName: AyaFont!, NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: textBackground])
        attributedText.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: " ﴿\((indexPath.row / API.readingDetail.count+1).toArabicDigit())﴾", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: MojezeRedColor, NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "XNazanin", size: AyaFont!.pointSize*0.65)!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: AyaParagraphStyle]))
        cell.ayaTextLabel.attributedText = attributedText

    }

    return cell
}
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: post cell for row at index path code...

Comment: estimation is suppose to be just that, an estimation, not a calculation of the exact height. As soon as the tableView is displayed, it is going to call that method for every cell to judge the height of the scrollbar. Meaning all 1000 cells are going to be calculated upon load

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Question edited and code added.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I know what estimation do but my question is why when I add estimation function it become more laggy and how I could add progress view, because when I seek to index 500 with scrollToRowAtIndexPath main thread become busy for scrolling.

Comment: @Aryan ... for the reason that I told you. Because the estimation is called for all the cells, not just the ones in view. Meaning it will make it laggy because it is doing 1000 calculations. You are suppose to calculate the height inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `EstimatedHeight...` is suppose to contain an estimation such as `return 40`

Comment: Have you tried to profile - what exactly function/instruction uses `CPU` dramatically?

Comment: `Because the estimation is called for all the cells` - @SimonMcLoughlin really? not for only visible cells?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I could not use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` because when I try to calculate cell height my calculated result is not correct, here is my code: `let size = (translations.suras[self.sura.index-1].ayas[index].text as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(maxSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: AyaFont as! AnyObject], context: nil)`

Comment: Result is not correct because you've missed font size I guess...

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan Font size is in font at attributes: `[NSFontAttributeName: AyaFont as! AnyObject]`

Comment: Ok, @Aryan you need to dig deeply into profiling to find expensive for CPU code, also it is good practice to calculate cell height once, cache that value and use it from cache.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan yes read the first paragraph under the `with estimation section`: [here](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios7-day-by-day-day-19-uitableview-row-height-estimation). Thats the purpose of estimation, you put your calculation inside `heightForRow`, you don't want that called for all rows straight away, but the tableView needs to know its contentSize, so it calls estimatedHeight for all rows to fill the gap. Thats why its suppose to be an incredibly lightweight response.

Comment: @Aryan, yeah, thanks, I missed font attribute..

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin thanks for pointing on that...